# Suppose that $K$ is a finite extension of $Q$ and that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$. Show that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that $K$ is a finite extension of $Q$ and that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$. Show that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $Q$.

The hint is to use the Tower Law. However, I don't see where I can use the Tower Law.

Comment: Let $x$ algebraic or non algebraic, what can you say about the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space ? $K$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space and $K(\alpha)$ is a finite dimensional $K$ vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the tower of fields

$\Bbb Q \subset K \subset K(\alpha), \tag 1$

with both

$[K(\alpha):K], [K:\Bbb Q] < \infty; \tag 2$

thus the tower law yields

$[K(\alpha):\Bbb Q] = [K(\alpha):K][K:\Bbb Q] < \infty; \tag 3$

since

$\alpha \in K(\alpha), \tag 4$

it follows then that $1$ and the first $n = [K(\alpha):\Bbb Q]$ powers of $\alpha$,

$1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^n \tag 5$

are linearly dependent over $\Bbb Q$; thus we have some

$q(x) \in \Bbb Q[x], \deg q \le n, \tag 6$

with

$q(\alpha) = 0, \tag 7$

the criterion for $\alpha$ to be algebraic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks! Beautiful proof! Just one question, why a^2...a^n have to be in K() even ∈()? I thought () only needs to be closed under addition?

Comment: @RandomThinker:  no, $K(\alpha)$ is defined to be the *smallest field containing both $K$ and $\alpha$*; that is, the smallest field with $K \subset K(\alpha)$ and $\alpha \in K(\alpha)$; thus $\alpha \in K(\alpha)$, a ***field***, so multiplicatively closed, so $\alpha^k \in K(\alpha), \; n \in \Bbb N$.  Oh yeah, thanks for the kind words and the "acceptance"!

Comment: I see! Thank you!